# Redshift SQL - Get the Right most section of Web URL

Tags: sql, string, amazon-redshift

I'm using a postgres database in Amazon Redshift and I need to get just the final section of a web URL and the following code works, but if I try to run it over a large number of records it makes the query hang and won't finish:

```
reverse(left(reverse(post_pg_url_txt),position('/' in reverse(post_pg_url_txt))-1))
```

Does anyone know a more efficient way to get all the text to the right of the final "/" in a web URL than the code I've pasted above?

Thanks in advance,
Steven

Answer (score 1):

option 1:

Use the [split_part function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) along with reverse for a *slghtly* better solution

```
reverse(split_part(reverse(post_pg_url_txt), '/', 1))
```

option 2:

Use the [regexp_count function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_COUNT.html) with split_part

```
split_part(post_pg_url_txt, '/', regexp_count(post_pg_url_txt, '/')+1)
```

As you see, option 1 is shorter two write.

Comment: cool... thank you for the fast feedback. I tested out your code and the first one works (but still makes the database hang) and the second one doesn't work (i get an error message "ERROR: function regexp_count(character varying, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: it's a postgres database on rds/aws. not sure if for some reason they have the function regexp_count disabled or something.

Comment: are you on redshift or postgresql? on postgresql you can write more consice code, of course a solution written for 1 database isn't guaranteed to work on another database. please clarify your question